# Laravel Order Address Relationship to Array

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

Hello I have a Query to create a PDF with that.

```
$data = Order::with('invoice')->with('delivery')->with('item')->find($id)->toArray();
```

That works fine. But The 'item' has a relationship to the Product Model.

How can i get the data of this product also in this query?

The current array is that.

```
0 => array:8 [▼
  "id" => 11
  "order_id" => 38
  "product_id" => 2
  "qty" => 999999
  "total" => "99999.99"
  "paid" => 0
  "created_at" => "2015-11-16 11:21:40"
  "updated_at" => "2015-11-16 12:35:33"
]
```

Comment: Did you try adding a `->with('item.product')`?

Comment: No, I don´t knew it.  Thank you. That´s the answer!!!

Comment: @WolfgangMüller Just another note, you don't have to chain them. You can pass multiple arguments to the `with` method and shorten it into this: `$data = Order::with('invoice', 'delivery', 'item.product')->find($id)->toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

So to close this question, you can eager load relations of relations using the dot notation:

```
->with('item.product')
```